# Optimizer and Handlebars client-side jade templates

Tags: javascript, requirejs, handlebars.js, optimization

I have an issue when trying to optimize client scripts that use client-side jade templating. Initially, I had an error as described in [Require.js + Backbone optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266808/require-js-backbone-optimization), but then I removed the "text" module from the paths configuration, added it to excludes and made text.js available locally.  After doing that, I get an error where the optmizer tries to resolve the parameter being passed to the text module.

Here's my client-side template:

```
define([
'Handlebars',
'text!/templates/product/something.jade'
], function(Handlebars, txtSomething) {
   var template = Handlebars.template, 
       templates = Handlebars.templates = Handlebars.templates || {};

   templates['something'] = Handlebars.compile(txtSomething);
});
```

And then the optimizer configuration:

```
({
  baseUrl: ".",
  name: "product",
  out: "product.js",
  paths: {
    Handlebars: "empty:"
  },
  exclude: ["text"]
})
```

And the error I get:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\templates\product\something.jade'
In module tree:
  product
    modules/something
      templates/something
        text
```

Any advice on how to resolve the issue?

Comment: a note on this implementation - it is in an express.js application, which has the path to the templates configured as follows:

    app.get("/templates/product/:template", function(req,res) {
      res.render("product/templates/" + req.params.template, { req: req}
    })

Comment: Do you have view config in your app.js (express)? Like app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

Comment: yes, that is set in app.js. however, when I run the optimizer, it doesn't run in the context of the app configuration. If I change the references to the view to 'text!../../../../views/product/something.jade' the optimizer runs without errors. but this breaks local development (IDE) configurations, and I need to use the URI-based references and not file-based references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I precompile the handlebars templates before running optimization. that removes the text references